# не могу нажать span или radiobutton в Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

никак не могу нажать на radiobutton после заполнения первых двух полей. Сайт: **https://capsule.dior.com/en/enter/hi**. Нужно нажать галочку на Mr и все галки справа.

пробовал следующий код:

```
mr = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "title1")))
mr.click()

mr = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#title1")))
mr.click()

mr = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id="title1"]")))
mr.click()
```

но все попытки безуспешные(

Comment: Безусппешные - значит клик ни к чему не приводит или значит `WebDriverWait` в итоге падает не найдя элемента?

Comment: так точно, возможно это связано с тем, что у элемента есть ::before и  ::after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте такой xpath: `//label[input[@id='title1']]`

Проверил у себя. Должен работать. В целом "правило большого пальца" такое: если какой-то элемент не кликается, попробуйте кликать на родительские элементы либо наоборот на те, что внутри.

Comment: спасибо за совет, но у меня не работает по такому xpath

mr = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[input[@id='title1']]")))
mr.click()

Comment: driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[input[@id='title1']]").click() # не работает тоже

Comment: У меня работает. Покажите код выбора тех пунктов которые активируют radio button.

Comment: сайт закрыли, но спасибо за отзывчивость, отмечу ваш ответ как правильный